# AngularJS - refresh ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using ng-repeat to display a collection of values. My filter options changes according to an ajax call to server. How can I refresh the ng-repeat after the filter parameters have been received?

**[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nssg30q/2/)**

Template

```
<div>
<div data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="item in values | filter:filterIds()"> 
            <code>#{{item.id}}</code> Item
        </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
 </div> 
<button ng-click="loadNewFilter()"> filter now</button>
```

Angular

```
var app = angular.module('m', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.values = [
   {id: 1},
   {id: 2},
   {id: 3},
   {id: 4},
   {id: 5},
   {id: 6}
  ];

  $scope.filter = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

  $scope.filterIds = function (ids) {
        return function (item) {
            var filter = $scope.filter;
            return filter.indexOf(item.id) !== -1;          
        }
  }

  $scope.loadNewFilter = function (){
    $scope.filter = [1,2,3];      
   }
});
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to tell angular that the values have changes:

```
$scope.loadNewFilter = function (){
    $scope.filter = [1,2,3];      
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

Comment: @user1477955 :http://jsfiddle.net/6nssg30q/6/

button is out of scope of controller. It works now

Comment: This solved an issue I was having wherein adding items to an array via a callback did not update the ng-repeat automatically. Calling $source.$apply(); right after adding a new item caused it to show up just fine.

Answer (score 9):

You have placed
`<button ng-click="loadNewFilter()"> filter now</button>` out of controller scope.

Comment: Funny, my next issue was how to call a click event in angularJS.  Thank you :)  +1

Answer (score 8):

In my case I had a trackBy in my ng-repeat and had to remove it to get it to update.

Comment: Precisely the same issue for me! Thank you - I'd not ever have expected tracyBy to *cause* a problem - I've only known it solves issues before!

Comment: @Meliodas you can use $index without trackBy

Answer (score 2):

After receiving your filter called $scope.$apply()  as following: It is refresh your scope.

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
     // your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I didnt need to use $scope.apply() to see the update. What solved this error for me was to make sure:

1. The update was being called from inside the controller.
2. The controller that called the update was the same that contained the ng-repeat.