# angularjs ng-repeat not updating after adding new data in ionic v1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

ng-repeat is not updating after adding new data and updating the $scope with new data. Here in my case user will add new address and it will return to the home view here the ng-repeat data is not updated with the latest address.

here is my code

```
        <ion-view ng-init="useraddresses()"  title='<img class="title-image" src="http://example.com/images/logo/Logo.png" width="49" height="43"/>' >
```

```
            <div id="placeorder">
      <h5 style="text-align:center">Place Your Order</h5>




      <div style="clear:both"></div>
      <a class="button button-positive" href="#/app/newaddress"> Add New Address</a>
      <!--<button >Add New Address</button>-->


      <h5>Pickup Address</h5>

      <ion-list >
          <ion-item id="{{x.id}}" ng-click="changes(x.id)" ng-repeat="x in addresses track by $index" style="width:50%;float:left;border:1px double black;min-height:150px;">
              <div style="width:100%;height:100%;">
                  <strong>{{x.address}}</strong>
                  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                  Landmark : {{x.landmark}}
                  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                  pincode : {{x.pincode}}



              </div>
          </ion-item>
      </ion-list>



      <div style="clear:both"></div>
      <button class="button button-block button-positive" style="background-color:#ec008c;" ng-disabled="placeorderbutton" ng-click="placeorder()"> Place Order</button>
  </div>
```

Here is my controller code

```
    $scope.useraddresses = function () {

    $scope.showloading();

    $http.post('http://example.com/RestServiceImpl.svc/getaddresses', { phone: localStorage.getItem('phone'), code: localStorage.getItem('code') },
 {
     headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
 })


 .then(data => {

     $scope.addresses.length = 0;

     $scope.addresses = data.data;
     // $scope.addresses = data.data

     console.log(data.data);

     $ionicLoading.hide();
 });
```

in the add new controller after adding the new address am using this navigate back to main page

```
  $state.go('app.search', {}, { location: "replace", reload: true, inherit: false });
```

I have tried cache false in routing and main page also but it did not worked.
please help me am developing app for my own store. am new to this ionic and angularjs. Thanks in advance

Comment: When you are navigating back to address list, are you getting new address in console.log(data.data)?

Comment: yes i am getting the new address in console.log(data.data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here iam using ng-init. ng-init is firing only once in app-cycle so here it is clearly explained like use ng-controller and ionicview.enter to solve this issue
[Run a controller function whenever a view is opened/shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27058276/run-a-controller-function-whenever-a-view-is-opened-shown)

here is the edited code

```
<ion-view ng-controller="indexController" ng-init="getaddress()"  title='<img class="title-image" src="http://washghar.com/images/logo/Logo.png" width="49" height="43"/>' >


 .controller('indexController', function ($scope, $http, $ionicLoading) {

$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function () {
    $scope.showloading();



    if (localStorage.getItem('userdetails') == 'complete') {

        document.getElementById('updateuserdetails').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('placeorder').style.display = 'block';



        $http.post('http://example.com/RestServiceImpl.svc/getaddresses', { phone: localStorage.getItem('phone'), code: localStorage.getItem('code') },
     {
         headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
     })
     .then(data => {

         $scope.addresses.length = 0;
         console.log(data.data);
         $scope.addresses = data.data;
         // $scope.addresses = data.data
         console.log($scope.addresses);

         // $scope.$apply();
         $ionicLoading.hide();
     });

    }
    else {

        document.getElementById('updateuserdetails').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('placeorder').style.display = 'none';
    }

    $ionicLoading.hide();
})




})
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you are getting the data in console.log(data.data) and referring to [AngularJS - refresh ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25843515/angularjs-refresh-ng-repeat), 
try adding $scope.$apply() after $scope.addresses = data.data;
so:

```
$scope.addresses = data.data;
$scope.$apply();
```

Comment: Sorry actually i am calling the the function before redirecting to this view. here the function itself is not called on ng-init. what to do now? Thank you